# How does the Round-Robin scheduling algorithm in Cloudsim manages the VMs allocation to Cloudlets, when there are multiple VMs?

Tags: algorithm, round-robin, cloudsim

In the Round-Robin scheduling algorithm in Cloudsim, it uses the quantum time to schedule the Cloudlets in the VM.
Now, if there are multiple VMs, How does it manage them? In other words, Is there any allocation plan for VMs?
Which Cloudlet for which VM?
Is there a queue for VMs too?

```
For example, there are 2 VMs and 6 cloudlets.
Cloudlets exec time= 12, 5, 10, 7, 15, 18
Quantum = 5
```

Can you guide me in an example? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here RR assign first cloudlet for 5 unit time to first VM and the second cloudlet for five unit time to second VM then, third cloudlet for 5 unit time to forst VM and 4th cloudlet for 5 unit time to second VM and so on.